# Single Payout in paypal in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payout

I've created a wallet system in which customer can buy products which seller added. after buying the product all payment will be transfer to admin's paypal account. What i need to do is after receiving payment some percent of payment will be stored in seller's wallet. and seller can request to withdraw that amount to admin.
In admin side after approving withdraw request specific seller should get paid in their paypal account from admin's paypal.
Simply i need to do paypal to paypal transfer via an email,

so i've used single payout API
but i'm getting pending error. trying to reach at the solution.
Someone's help will be most appreciated.

Response i've received is below:

stdClass Object
(
[batch_header] => stdClass Object
(
[payout_batch_id] => 83TEPJXBQJXZE
[batch_status] => PENDING
[sender_batch_header] => stdClass Object
(
[email_subject] => Test batch status
[sender_batch_id] => API-15
)

```
    )

[links] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts/83TEPJXBQJXZE
                [rel] => self
                [method] => GET
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

It is [normal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/integrate-api#link-sampleresponse) for payout batches to begin in a pending status. Check the status of the batch and individual payouts later. Register [for webhook notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#batch-payouts) if you wish.

---

Using Payouts in the live environment [requires approval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/integrate-api#link-knowbeforeyoucode)